# How can I make hindi pdf document in Latex without transliteration?

Tags: latex, hindi, miktex

I want to write a letter in Hindi. I want to use latex to create the pdf document in Hindi. I don't want to have transliteration from english to hindi.

Comment: This helped me a lot, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125899/5149

Answer (score 1):

Use `xelatex` (which uses UTF-8 input) with an appropriate font (e.g. Lohit).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}

\begin{document}
यह एक परीक्षण है
\end{document}
```